# Вызов статического метода класса из другого класса

Tags: c++

Подскажите, почему у меня из класса не получается вызвать статический метод другого класса, пробовал вызывать по-разному, так `Method.o(a, b);` и так `Method::o(a, b);`. К примеру в *C#* у меня подобным образом всё срабатывает.

```
#include <iostream>

class FirstClass
{
public:
    int a = 20, b = 20, c;
    FirstClass()
    {
        c = Method.o(a, b);
        cout << c << endl;
    }
};

class Method
{
public:
    static int o(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a + b;
        return c;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FirstClass a;
}
```

Comment: В с++ правильно так:  `Method::o(a, b);`

Comment: Но можно и так `((Method*)0)->o(a, b);` или так `Method x; x.o(a,b);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызываемый тип должен быть полностью определен перед вызовом. Это специфика C/C++

*То есть просто перенесите определение класса `Method` выше `FirstClass`.*

Ну и, как правильно заметил **nick_n_a**, вызов статического метода должен быть либо от имени типа через `::`, либо от переменной/указателя этого типа, через `.`/`->`

Comment: Ну вы хоть пример приведите. Ответ же ни о чём не говорит.

Comment: @nick_n_a Что конкретно вам непонятно в ответе?

Comment: Понятно, а как сделать что-бы не переносить класс?

Comment: @nammidd Дождаться, когда в C++ завезут модули. А если серьезно, в C++ принято выносить объявления классов в свои хэдеры, которые традиционно подключают в начале файла, в котором собираются их использовать (как вы поступили с iostream, например). Там есть еще интересные нюансы с случайным множественным включением хэдеров и необходимостью обращаться к методам друг друга для двух классов, но это уже другая история.

Comment: Хорошо бы сделать акцент на возможности переноса *определения класса* без необходимости наличия *определения функций* прямо в классе. Т.е. реализацию функции-члена `o` можно сделать в другом месте.

Answer (score 2):

В с++ не много по другому устроено адресное пространство.

1. Если вы хотите указать адресное пространство где находится метод, используется `::` т.е. нужно `Method::o(a, b);`
2. Если вы хотите вызвать метод из класса/интерфейса на которую создан указатель, используется `->` Например `Method * x; x->o(a,b);`  или `((Method*)0)->o(a,b)` (для статического можно с пустой ссылки вызов делать, такая запись не всегда корректна).
3. Если вы хотите напрямую или из класса вызвать метод используется `.` Например `Method x; x.o(a,b);` или вообще можно так `(*((Method*)0)).o(a.b);` (для статического метода условно можно).
4. Если у вас будет общее "именное" пространство с классом, то вложеный класс может напрямую без указания имени вызывать методы класса в который он вложен. Например так

   ```
   class FirstClass
   {
       static void call1(){};

       class Method{ 
           public:
           static int o(a,b) { call1(); };
       };
   }
   // А если вы хотите функцию объявить за пределами класса - это будет так:
   int FirstClass::Method::o(a,b) { /*Тело*/}
   ```

так же внутри namespace можно вызывать методы обьявленнные внутри этого namespace без указания namespace.

Comment: Я ничего о вложенности не писал. Более того, мне кажется это странной идеей. C++ и C# - это разные языки и ломать семантику ради похожего синтаксиса - это неправильно.

Comment: Всё бы хорошо, но вот: ссылочный тип спутан с указателем, а `динамический метод` и `прямой тип` вообще не свойственные C++ термины.

Comment: @free_ze. Перенос класса с методом вверх ефекта не даст, т.к. всёравно адресное пространство разное, я думал вы имеете ввиду что если класс обьявлен выше внутри класса откуда идёт вызов, то тогда не нужно использовать не одно из `:: . ->`. Иногда нужно вызвать динамический метод из статического, например обьявлено property которое возвращает по сути "статическое" значение, но вы его так просто не получите. А методами 2 и 3, можете получить.

Comment: Если под "ссылочным типом" подразумеваются ссылки, то используется ".", а не "->".

> Перенос класса с методом вверх ефекта не даст.
- Попробуйте.

Comment: Как уже указывали выше, в С++ нет ни динамических методов, ни property. Метод объекта вызывать из статического метода не нужно никогда. Если появляется такая необходимость, то этот метод должен был быть статическим. То, что вы написали - это указатель типа Method. Но в C++ есть еще такие понятия, как ссылки (Method&) и r-value ссылки (Method&&).

Comment: Ссылка - это `Method&` или `Method&&`. Со звездочкой - это указатель.

Comment: @alexout спасибо. Я указатель перепутал с ссылкой.

Comment: Адресное пространство _процесса_ никак не коррелирует с относительным расположением исходного кода. Адреса невиртуальных методов объектов и статических методов при вызове одинаково отсчитываются от "начала типа" в памяти. Но вы наверняка хотели сказать о пространствах имен (namespaces).

Comment: И мой ник тоже чутка :)

Answer (score 1):

если очень хочется не переносить весь класс `Method` выше `FirstClass` можете перенести только его объявление а определить ниже `FirstClass`. 
тоесть так:

```
class Method
{
public:
    static int o(int a, int b);
};

class FirstClass
{
public:
    int a = 20, b = 20, c;
    FirstClass()
    {
        c = Method::o(a, b);
        cout << c << endl;
    }
private:
};

int Method::o(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

или как уже было сказано, вынести определение типа `Method` в отдельный хедер и подключать его - и это по сути классический и самый верный спосбо, так как ещё происходит разделение интерфейса от реализации, хоть и на примитивном уровне